# Form validation linking fields as required

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am looking to do some client size validation.  Below you will find an example of my template.

When this form is submitted it is okay for a line to be empty.  However I want to be sure if even one item in a line is selected/has an entry that all lines will have an entry.  For example.  There should always be either Nothing OR require a Date, start Time, stop time, and class. (the class is populated by a button in another location)  The validation will be used to warn the individual if they are missing anything and if they submit we will disregard the record as incomplete.

I have looked at [jquery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org) as we are already using it on other forms in our project but, I have been unable to find a way to link row items together.

```
<form>
  <table id="payableEventTable" class="table table-condensed table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Class/Scenario</th>
        <th>Start</th>
        <th>Stop</th>
        <th>Break</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="payableEventTableBody">
      <c:forEach begin="0" end="5" varStatus="i">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="date" class="input-small" name="claimForm.payableEvents[${i.index}].eventDate" /></td>
          <td>
            <select class="classSelect" name="claimForm.payableEvents[${i.index}].event">
              <option></option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="claimForm.payableEvents[${i.index}].eventStartTime" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="claimForm.payableEvents[${i.index}].eventStopTime" /></td>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option value="0" selected>No Break taken</option>
              <option value="15">15 Minutes</option>
              <option value="30">30 Minutes</option>
              <option value="45">45 Minutes</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Technology we are willing to use. HTML, CSS, javaScript, jQuery, (lightweight plugins for jquery).  We also have to make sure the solution works back to IE8.

**Edit:**

I built a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnfz8/). To help with visualization.

**Edit:**

I have come up with an answer.  However, if anyone is able to improve on my answer, streamline it/make it look nicer I would still be willing to give out the Bounty to that person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion: To make your code more legible, you can combine the three functions `validateRow()`, `isRowEmpty()`, `isRowComplete()` into one simpler `validateRow()` function. Also it is a lot faster, because you only need to go through all elements and check their values once instead of twice.

I also created a simple to use `validateForm()` function to tidy things up.

The `validateForm()` function can now be used in an event handler:

```
// Event Handler
$('#validate').bind('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    if(validateForm()) {
        alert("next");
        //$('#claimWizard').wizard('next');
    }
});    


// Form Validation
var validateForm = function(){
    var valid = true;

    $('#payableEventTableBody tr').each(function() {
        if (validateRow($(this))) {
            $(this).removeClass("error");
        }
        else {
            valid = false;
            $(this).addClass('error');
        }
    });
    return valid;
}

var validateRow = function(row){
    var state = null,
        valid = true;

    row.find('input, select').each(function() {
        var value = $(this).val(),
            isEmpty = (value != 0 && value !== '');
        //if its the first element just save the state
        if(state === null) {
            state = isEmpty;
        }
        // if this field has not the same state as the rest
        else if(state !== isEmpty) {
            valid = false;
        }
    })   
    return valid;
}
```

And here's your fiddle with my code implemented: http://jsfiddle.net/KNDLF/

Answer (score 1):

So, what I came up with:

Three methods: `isRowValid()`, `isRowEmpty()`, `isRowComplete()`

The rows need to be either empty or complete.

```
//The following code is part of my logic on continuing
  var valid = true;
  $('#payableEventTableBody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('error');
    if (!isRowValid($(this))) {
      valid = false;
      $(this).addClass('error');
      return;
    }
  });

  if (valid) {
    $('#claimWizard').wizard('next');
  }


//The following is my validation methods
<script type="text/javascript">
  function isRowValid($tr) {
    return (isRowEmpty($tr) || isRowComplete($tr));
  }

  function isRowEmpty($tr) {
    var isEmpty = true;
    $tr.find('input, select').each(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      if (value != 0 && value !== '') {
        isEmpty = false;
      }
    });
    return isEmpty;
  }

  function isRowComplete($tr) {
    var isComplete = true;
    $tr.find('input, select').each(function(){
      var value = $(this).val();
      if(value === ''){
        isComplete = false;
      }
    });
    return isComplete;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be good to start with
http://jsfiddle.net/rJaPR/

```
$('#validate').bind('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#payableEventTable tr').each(function(){
            var tr = $(this);
            var newRowValue=0;
            $(tr).find('input, select').each(function(){
                var value = $(this).val();
                switch(newRowValue){
                    case 0:
                        // first input/select
                        newRowValue = ((value!=0 && value!='') ? 1 : -1);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        // there are some values in this row
                        if (value==0 || value=='')
                            tr.css('backgroundColor', 'red');
                        break;
                    case -1:
                        // this row should be empty
                        if (value!=0 && value!='')
                            tr.css('backgroundColor', 'red');
                        break;
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: Okay so it looks like the one thing it does not do,  Once tr turns red, if values are cleared out then clearing out values does not validate properly.  I.E.  setting the first class to breadmaking, validate, then setting it back to empty.  It continues to validate red.

Comment: Second thing, if I enter a valid response it does not seem to validate properly.

Comment: You wanted an idea on how to validate a row and this is you got. Sorry but removing red background on re-validation is so easy that I'm sure you can do it yourself. In the end I spend 5 min to show you the way you can go to get down voted... you make my day mate